# How can I compute a percentage based margin with LESS css?

Tags: css, less

I'm working with a fluid / responsive layout, based on a photoshop file based on a 960 grid. For one of the elements I want a 9px left margin when the layout is at 960px wide.

I've seen example doing this by computing 9/960, which comes out to `0.009375`, and setting:

```
margin-left: 0.009375%
```

However I'm using LESS css / LESS.app which can do math on variables and create them dynamically. 
I've tried these methods but they are throwing errors:

```
margin-left:9/960%;
margin-left:9/960\%;
margin-left:(9/960)%;
margin-left:{9/960}%;
```

How can I have LESS do the math on this automatically?

**Clarification**

If I use `margin-left:9/960;` LESS will compile but the output css is `margin-left: 0.009375;` which doesn't include the percentage sign and thus won't be rendered by the browser (AFAIK).

Comment: @Hauleth - I will clarify but I think the problem is that it doesn't add the "%" sign in the computed CSS and so the browser thinks the syntax is invalid

Comment: IMO work's fine `$ echo "*{width: (9/960)*100%;}" | .npm/less/1.3.0/package/bin/lessc -
* {
  width: 0.9375%;
}`

Comment: For future reference: Multiplying by a number with a percentage unit will work, but it's a but unclear why you are doing it, so future maintainers might mistake it and stumble into the same problem. The reason you are running into an error is that `%` is a string formatting operator, and apparently it doesn't treat variables and math followed by a percentage as something that can get % as a unit. To get your number as percentage, use the `percentage()` function: http://lesscss.org/#reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply multiply by 100%

```
$ echo "*{width: (9/960)*100%;}" | .npm/less/1.3.0/package/bin/lessc -
* {
  width: 0.9375%;
}
```

Comment: Ah, got it. At first I thought you were suggesting I had to move the decimal point two places. Thanks!